# GIT commit both to cloned repo (with new remote) and to the original repo

Tags: git

Not sure if the subject is comprehensible - let me clarify:

- I have a new project (call it "child") cloned from another project of mine (call it "master"); so now I have two repos, each with different remotes;
- now I'd like to commit and push from the "child" to its remote, but also I'd like to push only certain modification to the "master" remote - and vice versa.

What's the best solution to get this? (Maybe it has to do with upstream functionality?)

Comment: Instead of two local repos, don't you want _one_ local repo with _two_ remotes? That way you can pull from one and push to the other as desired.

Comment: Thank you Matt - never thought of that and could be an solution. However what I've had in mind was something like the solution by @Christian Fosli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add both remotes to the child project
(`git remote add upstream <url>`).

When you want to add something from child to upstream, I'd branch out from upstream/master.
If these changes are already in the child repo, you can cherry-pick them into the new branch.
Then push this branch and merge it into upstream's master.